# Is it safe to port 80 for the Mobile or embedded device

Tags: mobile, embedded

Let's say I have iPhone, or Android or Embedded system and I want to use Socket programming to establish a connection between them, Mobile to embedded system.

Is it OK to use port 80 of mobile and embedded system to establish the connection?

Can I hardcode port 80 into the code for both Mobile and embedded system?

Comment: Have you actually written code that will try to use port 80 on any of these systems?  If so, exactly what problems are you having?  Any error messages, missed communications, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, ports below 1024 are considered "privileged" on Unix-style systems, from which both Android and iOS inherit much of their basic under-the-covers functional design.

You will not be able to use port 80 on a secured (typical consumer, unhacked) Android device.

While I haven't tried it, I expect you will not be able to on an iphone either - iOS applications which I have seen which create a web server to expose selected data typically use higher port numbers in the unprivileged range.

You have two general options for picking the port number: guess a safe default (possibly already in customary use for the type of function you want - 8080 is a common choice for an unprivileged http server) and allow the user to change it if needed in some configuration menu, or pick a random free port and inform the user what it is so that they can enter that on the other end.

Also note that you will typically only be able to direct traffic to a phone when it is on a wifi network.  Putting the two requirements together, access to your embedded server would probably be via a URL something like

```
http://192.168.0.111:8080/somepage.html
```

Where of course the ip address, port number, and remainder of the URL are correct for you actual run time situation.